# Creating reorder giving grand total in double price

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I am creating a reorder functionality in magento.
It is creating with same info of order but showing the grand total double.
Last order  subtotal price $10 and shipping $5 so grand total is $15 
but in new reorder it is giving 25$
Below is the code for reodering process.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
        $order->setReordered(true);
         $newQuote = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
        $newQuote->setStoreId($order->getStoreId());
        $newQuote->assignCustomer(Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId()));
        $newQuote->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
        $model->setQuote($newQuote);
        $reorder = $model->initFromOrder($order);
        $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
             ->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod())
             ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
             ->collectTotals()
            ->save();
        $reorder->createOrder();
```

Comment: I am having same issue.Found any answer then please share details.

Answer (score 0):

I found some piece of code for this and want to share.May be help someone

```
 $orderId = 121; // Order Id not increment ID

Mage::unregister('rule_data');
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->clear();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$incId = $order->getIncrementId();

$newQuote = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
$newQuote->setStoreId($order->getStoreId());
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->setQuote($newQuote);

$order_model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
$order_model->getSession()->clear();

try {
    $order->setReordered(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);

    $reorder = new Varien_Object();
    $reorder = $order_model->initFromOrder($order);
    $newOrder = $reorder->createOrder();

    $reOrderId = $newOrder->getId();
    $reOrderIncId = $newOrder->getIncrementId();
    print_r("Order is Reorders To New Order #{$reOrderIncId} Successfully");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log("Reorder Error : {$e->getMessage()}",null,"order.log");
}
$reorder->getSession()->clear();
Mage::unregister('rule_data');
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->clear();
```